# MacVim doesn't redraw screen properly

Tags: save, macvim

Sometimes when I do something like saving, opening another file or another tab, the screen isn't changing states properly. At first I thought it was just my computer being slow, but then I noticed that after any keypress the screen updates and everything is okay.

It looks like this:

[image: Screen update bug]

but after a keypress everything updates and the file opens properly:

[image: Proper view]

What can I do to prevent this from happening? It's *really* annoying!

Comment: You should be able to press `<C-l>` to force a screen update. Other than that, this is either something in a plugin, or a bug... Try disabling all plugins.

Comment: The screen updates normally after any keypress; it's not that it gets stuck. But this brief period before next keypress just doesn't look pretty.

And I didn't mess with any of the plugins, nor have I installed any new the day this started; I'll try, but I don't think the problem is in there.

Comment: If this behavior continues after running `mvim -u NONE -U NONE -N`, and you're not running in fullscreen (or split screen on El Cap), you should probably [file a bug](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim) and we'll look at it. Note that there are a few outstanding issues with fullscreen/split-screen right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that the problem is gone. I didn't even notice when this happened, but I'm fine with that